# How to update planner task assignments using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-planner, microsoft-graph-plannertasks

When I tried to patch assignments to a task it only added on to existing ones. For example a task has assignments as `{A, B}`.

When I did patch assignments `{A, C}`, the assignments became `{A, B, C}` while I was expecting it to be updated to `{A, C}`. When I did patch assignments `{}` it didn't change anything while I wanted to remove all assignments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tried it myself but I am certain, if you patch with A's user Id with the null value to task endpit PATCH /planner/tasks/{id} should do the Magic

{
  "A's user Guid Id": null,
}

Don't forget the etag

Answer (score 2):

Assignments are updated independently. Any assignee not specified in the update will not be altered. So a request to change assignees from A,B to A,C looks like:

```
{
  "assignments": {
    "User id for B": null,
    "User id for C": { 
      "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.plannerAssignment",
      "orderHint": " !"
      }
    }
}
```